# Attach to app process on Windows Phone device

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windows-phone-8

I have a bug which only occurs when the application is downloaded through the store (not in the XAPs uploaded to the store). Unfortunately there was also a bug in the bug reporting code which ignored certain exceptions (for example if the device were offline) which means I have no idea where to start in fixing this! It's a pretty serious error that's crucial to the whole application (although it doesn't crash it) so I really don't want to have to do an additional submission to fix it!

Is it possible to attach to a process on a Windows Phone device?

Failing that is it possible to trick Visual Studio into debugging the XAP from the store? When deploy is unchecked in configuration manager, Visaul Studio errors.

Comment: My way of fixing these kind of bugs is to instrument the critical code with messageboxes and deploy a release version to the phone. After, detach the debugger and unplug the usb. If you are lucky you can repro the issue with the local xap and find out the root cause from the messages. Alternatively you can deploy a quick private beta submission.

Comment: Already tried release etc... I hadn't though of private beta though, that's worth a shot. How long do they take to certify?

Comment: Takes 2 hours, that's awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to debug this was as suggested by Andras Csehi in the comments above - through a private beta.

I believe the cause of the bug was due to the native SQLite being unable to find a temporary folder on WP8. To fix this it to tell SQLite to use in memory temporary storage which I've added to my fork of MvvmCross/SQLite-Net lib [here (line 212)](https://github.com/virblue/MvvmCross-SQLite/blob/master/Sqlite/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite/SharedFile/SQLiteNet.cs#l212).

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE && USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE
            // Without this large updates/inserts cause the database to fall
            // over with the error "Unable to open".
            this.Execute("PRAGMA temp_store = memory;");
#endif
```